# Visual Basic textbox1 of form 1 to textbox1 of form 2

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

How do I put the text contents of textbox1 of form 1 to textbox1 of form2?

For example i want to enter a name in the form1.textbox1 then I want it also to appear in form2.textbox1 but the user is not allowed to edit the name shown in the form2.textbox1

I will appreciate it if you will recommend other ways of doing it.

The first thing I thought that could work is `form2.textbox1.text = form1.textbox1.text` but it doesn't show the contents of textbox1 of form1 to textbox1 of form2.

Here is the screenshot of my simple program. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRvoU.jpg
In form1 i have a textbox and a button.
The user will input a text on the textbox and then if he click the button the program will go to the form2. In form2 I have a textbox. The textbox in form2 will show the text that the user entered in form1.

Comment: Please show how do you open the second form (the one where the user cannot type into the textbox)

Comment: by using a button.

the form 1 consists of a textbox where the user can write the name and a button that will show form2.

in the form2 it only consist of a textbox where i want the name of the user entered in form1 will also be shown in textbox1 of form2

Comment: The answer to your question is simple if a) You have an instance/reference of type Form1 and Form2 b) The text box in Form1 and Form2 is not private or protected. ...So if `form1` and `form2` is an instance/reference of type Form1 and Form2 then `form2.textbox1.Text = form1.textbox1.Text` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `TextChanged` event to easy "clone" its text.

**Form1.vb :**

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub TextBox_Form1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles TextBox_Form1.TextChanged

    Form2.TextBox_Form2.Text = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click

    Form2.Show()

End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2.vb :**

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.TextBox_form2.ReadOnly = True

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This works only with an automatic instance of Form2 not with an instantiated instance of Form2. And in my opinion is the Form2 instance that should act to update its controls not the Form1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a different approach. The second form (more specifically the instance of a Form2 class) should be responsible of its own controls. It should not allow external Forms instances to change its internal behavior. (In pure OOP parlance this is the encapsulation concept)

The only thing that the Form2 instance need to know is which external TextBox control it should monitor and display the changes that occur in this external control

So you could write something like this

In Form1 class click button

```
Public Sub button1_click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim f2 = new Form2(textBoxOnForm1)
    f2.Show()
End Sub
```

Here you pass, using a specific constructor of Form2, the reference to the textbox control that is hosted by Form1. In this way, any client code that want to reuse the functionality provided by the Form2 class need to pass the appropriate textbox.

Inside the Form2 class you add a new specific constructor that receives the TextBox passed when Form1 want to create the instance of Form2

```
public class Form2 : Inherits Form

    Sub New(ByVal textBoxOnForm1 as TextBox)

        ' Always required before acting on controls
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler textBoxOnForm1.TextChanged, AddressOf text_Changed
        textBoxOnForm2.Text = textBoxOnForm1.Text
    End Sub
```

Now, the Form2 class constructor have the reference to the external TextBox to monitor (whatever it comes from) and add the event handler that receives the TextChanged event of the TextBox passed (again, you don't mind where this TextBox control is located)

```
Sub text_Changed(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim tFromForm1 = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Me.textBoxOnForm2.Text = tFromForm1.Text
End Sub
```

The event handler just updates the internal textbox with the text of the external control. Now, if you want to implement a different behavior for the textChanged event you need to work only inside the class Form2

Answer (score 0):

on form 2:

```
Public Sub SetTextbox1Value(ByVal Value As String)
    TextBox1.Text = Value
End Sub
```

on form 1:

if automatic instance:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Form2.textboxInForm2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

if you defined the instance:

```
Private _form2 As New Form2
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    _form2.SetTextbox1Value(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    _form2.Show()
End Sub
```

note that a button for calling form 2 was added

the method in form 2 may be innecesary but I'm not sure how are you instantiating your form2.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to set the `Text` of the `TextBox` before `Form2` is initialised (shown) or after `Form1` has been released (closed). **Make sure both forms are open and try this**:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Form1.TextBox1.Text  
  End Sub    
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some value in one form to another form textbox then do this.

**Dim frmReport as new frmLogin
frmReport.textbox1.text=(What ever the value that you want to print)
frmReport.show()**

In this code frmReport is just a new veriable , you can define any name 
And frmLogin is my form name and i want to show the value in frmLogin Form textbox.
and after that you have to show the date like frmReport.show(), else the will not be displayed in the textbox